# How can I combine 2 models in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 2 models, each model has 2 primary keys(langId, topicCode).
How can I combine them to select the value?

```
const field_A = {langId: {type:DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true}, topicCode: {type:DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true}, data:{type:DataTypes.STRING}}
const field_B = {langId: {type:DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true}, topicCode: {type:DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true}, storage:{type:DataTypes.STRING}}
Model_A.init(field_A, { timestamps:false, sequelize });
Model_B.init(field_B, { timestamps:false, sequelize });
```

How can I perform the action as followings by using sequelize associations between models?

```
SELECT * from Model_A, Model_B where Model_A.langId = Model_B.langId and Model_A.topicCode = Model_B.topicCode
[
{
  langId: 'xx',
  topicCode: 'yy',
  data: 'zz',
  storage: 'pp',
},
{
  langId: 'gg',
  ...
}
]
```

Thank you. 
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize does not support composite keys in associations so you need to define associations with only one of keys and **always** indicate the `on` option in `include` option with conditions for both fields:

**association**

```js
modelA.belongsTo(modelB, { foreignKey: 'langId' });
```

**query**

```js
const modelAList = await ModelA.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: ModelB,
    on: {
      '$ModelA.langId$': Sequelize.col('ModelB.langId'),
      '$ModelA.topicCode$': Sequelize.col('ModelB.topicCode')
    }
  }]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I solved this problem as followings.     ModelA.belongsTo(ModelB, {foreignKey: "langId", targetKey:'langId'});
    ModelA.belongsTo(ModelB, {foreignKey: "topicCode", targetKey:"topicCode"})
Thanks again for your prompt answer, Anatoly.